# How are mysql data types processed at the moment of table creation?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, mysql-8.0

I was wondering if SQL actually does something with a column data type at the moment of table creation. I mean I understand that mysql needs it when inserting data to understand what is allowed to insert in it. But at the moment of table creation does SQL allocate different areas of memory or something like that? Or data types are only mandatory at the moment of table creation for the ease of future table insert statements?

Comment: based on data type don't allocate different areas of memory  .. is just mandatory  for manage properly the subsequent activities

Answer (score 1):

The datatypes are stored for use with queries.

During an `INSERT`, the data for the row being inserted is laid out based on the datatypes.  `INT` will use 4 bytes for a binary integer.  `VARCHAR(40)` will be laid out as a length plus up to 40 characters for a string.  `DATE` takes 3 bytes in a certain format.  Etc.

Most datatypes go in (via `INSERT`) and come out (via `SELECT`) as strings.  So, the string '2020-12-31', when used in a `DATE` is turned into the 3-byte internal format.

If you try to put the string '123xyz' into `INT`, it converts that string to an integer, and gets 123.  (This example is usually considered wrong, but that's what is done.)

When you `JOIN` two tables, the datatypes of the columns you are joining on *should* be the same.  If they are different datatypes, then one is converted to the other *if possible*.